# Flutter: How to export SQLite database as CSV?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter. I made an offline CRUD app using SQLite through this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xke5_yGL0uk

However, I couldn't find any tutorial on how to export the `Note` table onto a CSV file. How can I export the data out of SQLite in Flutter?

Comment: Did you find the answer? If yes, would you care to share with us?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am new on Flutter too and I was trying to download CSV file with Flutter Web. I will add my working code here maybe it can work for you too.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

class ExportCsv {
  final List data;
  ExportCsv({this.data});

  List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
  downloadData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      List<dynamic> row = List();
      row.add(data[i].userName);
      row.add(data[i].userLastName);
      row.add(data[i].userEmail);
      rows.add(row);
    }

    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
    new AnchorElement(href: "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,$csv")
      ..setAttribute("download", "data.csv")
      ..click();
  }
}
```